# Reverse of a set of numbers given a limit

Tags: math, numbers, formula

I have a part of my code that gives me a floating point number from 0 to 1.0.  I've been trying to reverse the code to give me the inverse, but I'm having a lot of trouble with that...am I brain dead in thinking there should be a mathematical way to just invert the number somehow?

Like if the result is 1, the answer is 0, vice versa.  If the number is .25, the answer will be .75, again vice versa...

Comment: Why not just "inverted = 1 - given"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

> inverted_number = limit - number;

e.g. 
limit = 1
     
number = 0.33
     
inverted_number = 1 - 0.33 = 0.67